# Display a live plot as the program runs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm having troubles with using matplotlib to display live graphs. I'm very new to this so sorry if it is simple question

My python program runs a c script as a subprocess, where in that c script data is continuously sent to stdout (4 times a second for example), where python then reads the stdout, plots it and (crucially) updates the x axis as time progresses

This all works perfectly, but the plot is only shown after the program closes. I'd like to be able to view this graph as it runs (I think I've seen something called matplotlib animate which I am trying to use)

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Start the C program as a subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['./myprogram'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Skip the first 115 lines of the std output
for i in range(115):
    p.stdout.readline()



# Create an empty list to store the numbers
numbers = []

# Create a function to update the plot
def update_plot():
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(numbers)
    plt.ylim([0, 1500]) # Set the y-axis limits
    plt.draw()

# Set the plot to update every second
timer = plt.gcf().canvas.new_timer(interval=1000)
timer.add_callback(update_plot)
timer.start()

# Continuously read the output of stdout
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    number = float(line[26:]) #skip the first 26 characters of the line
    numbers.append(number)


plt.show()
```

I have tried to implement the animate function but don't really understand it.